# QGIS 3.22.12: change size of Menu panel

Tags: qgis, panel, size

Is it possible to change (reduce) the height of the menu panel? My screen is not so big and I would like to have a more compact menu panel. When I change the icon size, I can only choose between 24 (standard) and 16  - then the icons get very small, but the height of the panels does not change. My OS is ubuntu 22.04 [image]

Comment: Noy sure of the height, but you may 1) turn off toolbars you don't need/use and/or 2) move the toolbars from 3rd row onto the 2nd row. You can also put toolbar(s) in portrait (vertical) at the left (or right) of your screen. 3) You may turn off specific tools on a toolbar (so the toolbar get shorter to better fit in on the same" meny row"). Settings > Interface Customization > enable customization. Scroll down to Toolbars and choose a bar and turn off tools you don't/rarely use.

Comment: thanks a lot! This <<<Settings > Interface Customization > enable customization. Scroll down to Toolbars and choose a bar and turn off tools you don't/rarely use>>> was new for me, and helps a lot! But neverthelesss maybe there is a possibility to reduce the height of the panel.

Comment: There is an open issue on QGIS GitHub page: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46039

Comment: @9ls1 this would be a valid answer, in my view

Comment: I think my problem is a little different: when I reduce Icon size from 24 to 16, then all icons reduce their size. But the toolbar remains as big as before.